# Comparing rows of two tables in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, compare, left-join, hiveql

I want to compare two tables in HIVE. More specifically, I want to see if table2 has any rows that are not in table1, and vice versa. So far I have this:

```
select count(A.PERS_KEY) from
table1 A left outer join table2 B
on A.PERS_GEN_KEY = B.PERS_KEY
where B.PERS_KEY IS NULL;
```

But this will only check for the PERS_KEY. How would I check to see if an entire row is in one table but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can check based on `pers_key`. However, i am not sure why you would compare the entire row.

```
select pers_key from table1 
where pers_key not in (select distinct PERS_GEN_KEY from table2)

select pers_gen_key from table2 
where pers_gen_key not in (select distinct pers_key from table1)
```